# Swift set current Font in addAttribute

Tags: swift, nsattributedstring

I have a plus button to increase the font size and a minus button to reduce the font size. Now I've tried to use a searchbar to highlight words in my textview. It works very well so far, but unfortunately the current font size is not kept, but it returns it to the default font size. My solution would be to call addAttributes and specify .font, unfortunately I do not know what to put in value and range.

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

do
    {
        if let searchString = searchBar.text, let baseString = textNotiz.text {

            let attributed = NSMutableAttributedString(string: baseString)
            attributed.addAttribute(.font, value: "??", range: "??" )
            if searchString.count > 0 && baseString.count > 0 {

                let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: searchString,options: .caseInsensitive)
                for match in regex.matches(in: baseString, options: NSRegularExpression.MatchingOptions(), range: NSRange(location: 0, length: baseString.count)) as [NSTextCheckingResult] {
                    attributed.addAttribute(.backgroundColor, value: UIColor.yellow, range: match.range)
                }
                self.textNotiz.attributedText = attributed

            } else {

                textNotiz.attributedText = attributed

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: If I understood the issue is that you are creating each time a new attributedText `let attributed = NSMutableAttributedString(string: baseString)`. Instead, do `if let currentAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: baseString)`, and use `currentAttributedString` instead of `attributed`, it should work. (and remove the `attributed.addAttribute(.font, value: "??", range: "??" )`.

Comment: If that's not that issue you are having, then `attributed.addAttribute(.font, value: textNotiz.font, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: baseString.utf16.count)` for the line `attributed.addAttribute(.font, value: "??", range: "??" )`